# Java -Comparing values from objects in an ArrayList

Tags: java, oop, user-interface, arraylist

So basically I have a program where I add pc's to an array list and have to pick out the best one of them (depending on score/price mathematical operation) meaning a pc with a score of 10 and price of 5 would be better than one with a score of 10 and a price of 10.The problem is a boolean(isBetterThan) method which must be implemented and somehow used to compare them and I can't figure out exactly how).
Here's the code so far:

```
    package filipapp;

public interface Better {
    public double getPrice();
    public void setPrice(double price);
    public int getScore();
    public void setScore(int score);
    public boolean isBetterThan(Object obj);
}
```

Class

```
    package filipapp;

public class Computer implements Better {
    private String model;
    private double price;
    private int score;
    public Computer (String model,double price,int score){
        this.model = model;
        this.price = price;
        this.score = score;
    }
    @Override 
    public double getPrice(){
        return price;
    }
    @Override
    public void setPrice(double price){
        this.price = price;
    }
    @Override 
    public int getScore(){
        return score;
    }
    @Override
    public void setScore(int score){
        this.score = score;
    }
    @Override 
    public boolean isBetterThan(Object obj){
        obj = getScore()/getPrice();
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return ("Model "+model+" at price: "+price+" with score: "+score);
    }
}
```

GUI

```
 package filipapp;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FilipApp extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JLabel l1,l2,l3;
    private JTextField t1,t2,t3;
    private JPanel p1,p2,p3;
    private JButton b1,b2;
    private JTextArea area;
    private JScrollPane scroll;
    public Computer p;
    ArrayList <Computer> pc = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
           @Override
           public void run(){
               new FilipApp().setVisible(true);
           }
       });
    }
    public FilipApp(){
        super("The best PC");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600,400);
        Container container = this.getContentPane();

        p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
        l1 = new JLabel("Model",JLabel.CENTER);
        p1.add(l1);
        t1 = new JTextField(15);
        p1.add(t1);
        l2 = new JLabel("Price",JLabel.CENTER);
        p1.add(l2);
        t2 = new JTextField(15);
        p1.add(t2);
        l3 = new JLabel("Score",JLabel.CENTER);
        p1.add(l3);
        t3 = new JTextField(15);
        p1.add(t3);
        container.add(p1,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        p2 = new JPanel();
        b1 = new JButton("Add");
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        p2.add(b1);
        b2 = new JButton("Best");
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        p2.add(b2);
        container.add(p2,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        p3 = new JPanel();
        area = new JTextArea(15,35);
        scroll = new JScrollPane(area ,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        p3.add(scroll);
        container.add(p3,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        pc = new ArrayList <>();
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        try{
            Object source = e.getSource();
            if (source == b1){
                p = new Computer(t1.getText(),Double.parseDouble(t2.getText()),Integer.parseInt(t3.getText()));
                pc.add(p);
                area.append("Added PC  \n"+p.toString()+"\n");
                t1.setText("");t2.setText("");t3.setText("");
            }
            else if (source == b2 && pc.isEmpty()){
                area.append("Empty List \n");
            }
            else if (source == b2){
              for (Computer element : pc){

                  element.isBetterThan(element);
                  area.append("Best PC: "+element.toString()); 
              }
            }
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
             System.out.println("Error in input data");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tough to answer. What have you tried? You want logic? Algorithm? Syntax? Structure?

Comment: We need more details on your algorithm/system. Are `score` and `price` always out of 10?

Comment: Hmm I've been playing with the code for a while now so I did try a few things, but none of them seemed to give me the result i want. Syntab would be perfect if possible.The main problem here is this boolean method since I can't get to the logic of how to use it at all.No I just gave those numbers as an example.Score and Price can be any Integer/Double numbers you want them to be.The point is to take out the PC with the best proportion of score/price by comparing them somehow.

Comment: I would create a way to generate a score, basically, something like score per unit currency, and then store those in the object and stream maximise based on that field. If you really want something that gives a boolean-like object, then I would simply implement the comparator interface.

Comment: I worked it out.Thanks to everyone in the answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In yout loop, you should use a tempo variable to act as best item.

```
       else if (source == b2){
          Computer best = pc.get(0); // Depend on your logic, you should verify if the pc list is empty or not before get(0)
          for (int i = 1; i < pc.size(); i++){
              Computer element = pc.get(i);
              if (element.isBetterThan(best)) {
                   best = element;
              }
          }
          // When loop exits, you have access to the best pc
          area.append("Best PC: "+best.toString()); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well First and foremost if it is "better" than another is subjective i see that you are using `getScore()/getPrice()` to make that judgement so i'll continue assuming that is fine.

The first thing to understand is that `isBetterThan` is comparing `this` which is a `Computer` object with another computer object. so to start the interface should look like

```
public boolean isBetterThan(Computer comp);
```

then implimenting it using your division logic would look like

```
public boolean isBetterThan(Computer comp){
    if((this.getScore()/this.getPrice()) <
             comp.getScore()/comp.getPrice()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```